# Android UIAutomator how to tilt device

Tags: android, android-testing, android-uiautomator

is there anyway to perform tilt action using uiautomator android? I looked at the uiautomatorAPI but i am unable to find any direct method.

Answer (score 3):

There are methods that change the device orientation. I assume this is what you want.
You could try:

```
getUiDevice().setOrientationRight();
getUiDevice().setOrientationLeft();
getUiDevice().setOrientationNatural();
```

For more details on how to use them you can access the link:
[auiautomator UiDevice](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/uiautomator/UiDevice.html)

Comment: I checked those methods but those are just for rotating the device. but i want to tilt the device like using device accelrometer. Is there anyway to do that thing? I am unable to find any :(